# Выбор платформы для написания программы

Tags: c#, база-данных

Добрый всем вечер (день, утро, ночь).
Собираюсь написать небольшую программу для планирования и учета факта оказания услуг клиентам, выгрузки в региональные органы власти отчетов в формате Эксел.
Сейчас эти задачи решаются в экселе. Но, естественно, работать неудобно.
Планирую использовать C#. Изучаю.
Но есть пара проблем. Пока пара.))
1. Какую платформу использовать для разработки оконного интефейса Windows Forms или Windows Presentation Foundation?
2. Какую СУБД выбрать FireBird, MySQL или MS SQL Express?

Какие преимущества или минусы можно выделить при сравнении программного обеспечения? Возможно есть типовые решения?

Прошу совета.

Comment: WPF и PostgreSQL. А именно Стендэлон нужен? Почему не смотрите в сторону web-решения?

Comment: Можно и web. Самое время определиться пока не начал.

Comment: А почему WPF и PostgreSQL?

Comment: Если выбор между WPF и Windows Forms, то, очевидно, WPF следует брать. Больше возможностей, проще разработка идёт.

Comment: По поводу же базы данных. Если нет особых требований, то разницы особой нет. Просто мне постгресс больше нравится. Но если уж решите брать MySQL, то лучше посмотрите на его форк - MariaDB.

Comment: Ок. Спасибо. Посмотрю.

Comment: Если планируется много пользователей, то проще и удобнее сделать web решение, если не много пользовательское, то подойдет WPF и SQLite

Comment: ОК. Пользователей как раз не много. WPF уже начал изучать. Спасибо.